# FFmpeg: Exporting subtitle stream to .ass file

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

What I'm trying to do is exporting the subtile stream of a MKV-file to a ASS-subtitle-file.
I'm not really experienced with ffmpeg so I'm sorry if I miss something obvious

This is what I've got so far:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:7 -c:s ass output_subtitle.ass
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me the error "Only SUBTITLE_ASS type supported"

Comment: By the way, why not use str?

Comment: Hm, what are the advantages of using str?

Comment: Lighter, simpler, more widely supported and it's not like ass has that much to offer that str hasn't. Unless you want some really fancy formatting.

Comment: Well, how do you define "fancy formatting"? The subtitle got a custom font and color :D

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: Too long to post here...

Comment: Nobody has said that before. You may, of course, omit multiple repeating lines. If you are unsure just provide the first ~50 and last ~50 lines.

Comment: Well I found a line that may be interesting:
`[matroska,webm @ 0x7fb421018600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 7 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options'`

Comment: And the last lines:

    Chapter #0.1: start 325.575250, end 612.278333
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02

[…] (Lots of chapters)

    Stream #0:0(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Untertitel
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (pgssub -> ass)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[ass @ 0x7fb422417c00] Only SUBTITLE_ASS type supported.
Subtitle encoding failed

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:{subtitle_stream_index} -c copy output_subtitle.ass
```

assuming the subtitle stream index is 7 from your question
then the command will be

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:7 -c copy output_subtitle.ass
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vn -an -codec:s:0.7 ass output_subtitle.ass` assuming you have found out the stream identifier to be 0:7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but somehow it still gives me the same error. Maybe it is relevant that the subtitle stream has a pgssub codec?

Comment: Have you tried to export str instead?

Comment: Yes, I did but it leaves me with a new error:
"Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

Command I used:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vn -an -codec:s:0.7 srt output_subtitle.srt`

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Is it "SRT" or "STR"?!